# How invoke dpkg-buildflags for manual compilation?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, debian

On Debian stretch when trying to manually compile e.g. libpopt (I'm not intending to create debian packages), after I did
`export DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=hardening=+all`
I've trouble passing dpkg-buildflags to `./configure`:

```
./configure $(dpkg-buildflags --export=cmdline)
configure: error: unrecognized option: -O2
Try `./configure --help' for more information.
```

If I do:

`dpkg-buildflags --export=cmdline`

I get:

```
CFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/popt-1.16=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security" CPPFLAGS="-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2" CXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/popt-1.16=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security" FCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/popt-1.16=. -fstack-protector-strong" FFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/popt-1.16=. -fstack-protector-strong" GCJFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/popt-1.16=. -fstack-protector-strong" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now" OBJCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/popt-1.16=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security" OBJCXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/popt-1.16=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security"
```

When I now pass this output manually (copy&paste) to `./configure` it works:

```
./configure CFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/popt-1.16=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security" CPPFLAGS="-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2" CXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/popt-1.16=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security" FCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/popt-1.16=. -fstack-protector-strong" FFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/popt-1.16=. -fstack-protector-strong" GCJFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/popt-1.16=. -fstack-protector-strong" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now" OBJCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/popt-1.16=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security" OBJCXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/popt-1.16=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security"
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
[...]
```

How can I invoke dpkg-buildflags to automatically pass its flags to `./configure`?
Why does manual copy&paste work but not the other approach?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does manual copy&paste work but not the other approach?

This is related to argument escaping. Consider the following function:

```
# This function simply prints its arguments, each on separate line
test () {
    for arg in "$@"; do
        echo "$arg"
    done
}
```

This is what happens when you pass the output of `dpkg-buildflags` manually:

```
$ test ROSES=red VIOLETS=blue CFLAGS="-O0 -ggdb"
ROSES=red
VIOLETS=blue
CFLAGS=-O0 -ggdb
```

Note that `CFLAGS=-O0 -ggdb` is seen as a single argument, so escaping works.

Now let's try to evaluate an inline expression:

```
$ test $(echo ROSES=red VIOLETS=blue CFLAGS="-O0 -ggdb")
ROSES=red
VIOLETS=blue
CFLAGS=-O0
-ggdb
```

Boom! Somehow `CFLAGS=-O0 -ggdb` got broken into `CFLAGS=-O0` and `-ggdb`. The same is happening in your case: the value of `CFLAGS` gets split into multiple arguments, and indeed `-O2` is not a valid option. This is why you're getting an error.

> How can I invoke dpkg-buildflags to automatically pass its flags to `./configure`?

You can work this around using a pipe and xargs command:

```
dpkg-buildflags --export=cmdline | xargs ./configure
```

This solution works for me.